# iPhone SDK: Buttons and Labels causing UIScrollView to not scroll

Tags: uiscrollview, uibutton, uilabel

I have been dealing with this all day and I simply cant find what the heck is going wrong. I have a scrollview inside a viewcontroller, but when i add a label or button to the view the scroll view stops scrolling. This is so standard i've done it hundred of times but for some reason its acting up now. Hope someone can help.

.h

```
@interface Test : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;


}

-(IBAction)goBack;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface Test ()

@end

@implementation Test

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320.0,1100.0);

}

-(IBAction)goBack
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: verify if the userInteraction is enabled

Comment: yes user interaction is enable. Everything is working, until the buttons are added